# Adding array into excel using openpyxl (formatting issue)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, openpyxl

I am using "openpyxl" to put an array into an excel file for users to download on a django site.

The data goes into the excel  fine using the following loop:

```
for row_num, row in enumerate(matrix, 3):
 for col_num, item in enumerate(row, col_start - 12):
        ws.cell(column=col_num, row=row_num, value=item)
wb.save(excel_file_path_from_db)
```

My problem is that when the data enters the excel is is not in number format.  I think it could be because i am getting my atix values from a user input via:

```
matrix = ast.literal_eval(list(request.GET)[0])
print(matrix)
```

Any ideas how I can make my matrix come into the excel file in number format?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have string values.  The cell() function will set the data_type property of the resulting openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell object to try and match that.

If you assign the output of cell() to a variable (cell, for example):
`cell = ws.cell(column=col_num, row=row_num, value=item)`

And then `print(cell.data_type)`, you will likely get "t" for text.

You should be able to use a cast operator on `item` when you invoke ws.cell():

```
for row_num, row in enumerate(matrix, 3):
 for col_num, item in enumerate(row, col_start - 12):
    ws.cell(column=col_num, row=row_num, value=float(item))
wb.save(excel_file_path_from_db)
```

Another option that worked for me:

```
for row_num, row in enumerate(matrix, 3):
 for col_num, item in enumerate(row, col_start - 12):
    cell = ws.cell(column=col_num, row=row_num, value=item)
    cell.data_type = "n"
wb.save(excel_file_path_from_db)
```